# How to emit custom metrics from SpringBoot application and use it in PCF Autoscaler

Tags: java, spring-boot, prometheus, cloud-foundry, micrometer

I am following this [example](https://github.com/pivotal-cf/metric-registrar-examples/tree/master/java-spring-security) for emitting the custom metrics and followed [these details](https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/2-4/metric-registrar/using.html) for registering the metrics in PCF.

Here is the code:

```
@RestController
public class CustomMetricsController {

    @Autowired
    private MeterRegistry registry;     

    @GetMapping("/high_latency")
    public ResponseEntity<Integer> highLatency() throws InterruptedException {
        int queueLength=0;
        Random random = new Random();
        int number = random.nextInt(50);
        System.out.println("Generate number is : "+number);
        if(number % 2 == 0) {
            queueLength=99;
        } else {
            queueLength=200;
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(queueLength, null, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

application.yml:

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "metrics,prometheus"
  endpoint:
    metrics:
      enabled: true
    prometheus:
      enabled: true
```

SecurityConfiguration class:
[image]

build.gradle dependencies part:
[image]

Steps I followed to register the custom metrics after app deployment to PCF:

1. Installed `metric-registrar` on my local machine
2. Registered endpoint that emitting some Integer(which I am using for Autoscaler Rule) 
   `cf register-metrics-endpoint api high_latency`
   After this step I can see one Custom-User-Provided service is bounded with my app in PCF.
   [image]
3. Installed `log-cache` plugin on my local to verify the metrics endpoint and here are the logs
   [image]
4. At last I added the rule in Autoscaler for custom metric.
   [image]

This is the error I am getting in Autoscaler event history.

> EVENT HISTORY Most Recent: Wed July 17, 2019 at 11:20 AM Autoscaler
>   did not receive any metrics for high_latency during the scaling
>   window. Scaling down will be deferred until these metrics are
>   available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into this a big. A few things here...

1. I believe your registration command is wrong, at least for the sample app you referenced.

   You're using `cf register-metrics-endpoint api high_latency`, which means you have an app named `api` and an endpoint on that app at `high_latency` which exports metrics using the Prometheus format. For this sample app, the path should be `/actuator/prometheus`, according to the README & my brief test.

   When I used the command `cf register-metrics-endpoint app-name /actuator/prometheus`, I was able to see the custom metrics in the output from `cf tail` & I do not see them in your included output.

   Ex: (not showing up in your screenshot)

   ```
   2019-07-17T22:54:37.83-0400 [custom-metrics-demo/0] GAUGE tomcat_global_request_max_seconds:2.006000
   2019-07-17T22:54:37.83-0400 [custom-metrics-demo/0] GAUGE system_cpu_count:4.000000
   2019-07-17T22:54:37.83-0400 [custom-metrics-demo/0] COUNTER tomcat_sessions_created_sessions_total:12
   2019-07-17T22:54:37.83-0400 [custom-metrics-demo/0] COUNTER custom_metric_total:15
   2019-07-17T22:54:37.83-0400 [custom-metrics-demo/0] GAUGE jvm_gc_pause_seconds_sum:0.138000
   2019-07-17T22:54:37.83-0400 [custom-metrics-demo/0] COUNTER jvm_gc_pause_seconds_count:25
   ```
2. In the referenced sample app, there is no metric called `high_latency`, so that won't work as the name of your metric, as it will never get generated by the app. You can see all the metrics if you access the `/actuator/prometheus` endpoint in your browser. The Prometheus format is text based and pretty easy to read.
3. The last one is tricky and not documented but I can see it in the code for Autoscaler (at the time of writing this). When Autoscaler polls for metrics from LogCache, it only pulls GAUGE & TIMER events, not COUNTER events. If you were to try and use `custom_metric` from the demo app that would not work because it is a COUNTER metric. You'll just see the message about Autoscaler not seeing any metric events during the scaling window. Make sure that you are picking a GAUGE metric to use for scaling.
4. It also does not appear that Autoscaler supports using metrics with associated tags. If for example, you wanted to use `tomcat_servlet_request_seconds_sum{name="dispatcherServlet",}`, I don't think there's a way to tell Autoscaler that the `name` tag is required to be a certain value. That info is in LogCache, but I don't think Autoscaler uses it at this time. My quick glance through the code, at the time I write this, seems to indicate it's only looking at the metric name. If you're creating a custom metric, this won't matter. Just don't use any tags for the metric.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, really appreciate your time.
I still got the same error and after spending some more time with Infrastructure team I found out that I am still using `PCF 2.3` which doesn't support `Registering and Emitting Custom App Metrics`, needs to wait to implement this till team updates the PAS to 2.4 or 2.5.